# null pointer exception with dates after Struts upgrade to 2.3.34

Tags: ajax, nullpointerexception, datepicker, struts2, dojo

All parameters entered from UI are passed properly on method call except date values which are returned as null values, hence resulting null pointer exception.

Previously used struts version is 2.3.15 v, everything worked fine in that version.
Recently upgraded to struts2 2.3.34v (currently allowed in our project).

Other jars which we are currently using are:
All struts2 core jars and dependency jars version 2.3.34
jmaki 1.1 version and ajax wrapper jar 1.0.3 version
struts2 dojo plugin 2.3.15

I tried different solutions but of no use. Below are few solutions I tried.

1. Replaced dojo plugin to new version 2.3.34 and added its dependency jars.
2. Changing type of date to string to support dojo with latest jars.
3. jmaki api upgrade-ajax enabled framewor--->replacing ajax-wrapper-comp-1.0.3 jar to new version 1.8.1, also used along with latest dojo plugin.
4. Changes in jsp and changed public id in xml to latest

It's not a db related issue, we checked it. We are using jmaki 1.1 which wraps widgets provided by dojo, yahoo and others for supporting ajax. Please suggest us if any other options to be tried.

I understand dojo plugin is deprecated from struts 2.5x version, but everything worked fine with 2.3.15 struts ver but after upgrading to S 2.3.34 version facing this issue with dates.

Comment: In fairness, the Dojo plugin has been deprecated for years. I'd start by checking your request on the wire (e.g., network tab), checking parameter white/black/etc-listing, seeing what's in the params interceptor. IOW, start tracking from the source (the request) and see where things go bye-bye.

Comment: More or less it can be a dependency issue or version mismatch error.

Comment: I checked with all version jars, but nothing worked out..Date parameters are still returned as null values. Is there any other alternate option that could work with jmaki?

Comment: You can write a plugin for jmarki.

Comment: Does Jmaki works with latest struts JQuery plugin. There are no much resources available.

Comment: Actually, after struts upgrade, date parameters are not mapping to struts action. Setter methods are not called for those values. Hence, default values are sent. I checked it with all version dojo and other struts core jars, but nothing worked. Why input date is not mapping to action. Does struts2 jquery plugin can help me in this issue?

Comment: This is not an issue with jquery and plugin that used with struts2.

Comment: I can just see null pointer exception in my logs. While debugging the code, its clear that date parameters are skipping setter methods. In struts.xml, for this action, result type is json. Is this issue related to json deserialization.